# How can you import a public member from dll

Tags: c++, dll

I have this example c++ class in a dll library

```
class Rectangle {
  public:
    int width, height;
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area (void);
} rect;
```

and I've exported everything with a .def file
when importing the dll i have access to the two functions
(set_values(int,int) and area(void))
but not to the public variables (width and height)

How van I get access to these variables

Comment: class __declspec(dllimport) Rectangle { ... } ;  Rectangle r; r.width r.height ?

Comment: And you can add _ZN2[blabla]width @5 DATA _ZN2[blabla]height @6 DATA to the .def file. But you'd better to __declspec(dllexport) to the class

Comment: Why can we not see the DEF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dllexport to export your functions in a dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool void set_values (int,int);
```

You can also use dumpbin to generate definition file

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS tryDLL.dll > tryDLL.def
```

And then use lib.exe to build the .lib file which will work with your dll file:

```
lib /def:try.def /out:trydll.lib
```

Once properly exported, you can copy the DLL file in your application folder and include the directory and the lib file ( or use #pragma)  into your project. Your exported class and function definitions should be declared in a header file, which still needs to be included in your project. That assured,  your member function can be called like in any other ordinary program. You can access static member variables and constants declared in your dll declarations.

Comment: I don't want to export only the functions but also the variables width and height

Comment: Declare them as constants or static in your class and use properties to get the return value. You can get return values for static members ( hence single instance) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Definition files should be considered deprecated. In order to export classes, you should append the dllimport or dllexport attributes after the “class” keyword. While linking against your library, you should do so against the MSVC generated static (.lib) library that can be found in the same directory as your dynamic library

See: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (how to solve the problem using definition files, or whether it is possible). Also, where does it say that definition files are deprecated?

Comment: The question never mentioned that module definition files should be used; the question was asking how can one access certain cpp class members and symbols from a dll. Secondly, nobody said that they were deprecated, as they’re just condemned for legacy use. With dllexport and dllimport, you have no reason to use definition files, providing that you actually have the source to the library in question.

Comment: “This does not answer the question,” no, I just didn’t spoon feed code for him to copy and paste for later questions

Comment: i do have access to the library's source, i have successfully exported the  functions, my issue is how to export the variables width and height